# Is there a way to set an inline style on an href link on "a:hover" in a html email?

Tags: html, css, email

The question is to know if there is a way to build an HTML email with inline style (no CSS file, nor `<style>` tags) with the href links that react with the mouse passing over them : just to be able to change the color font.

So, no JS, no script, no `<style>`, just `<a href="http://www.dot.com style="....">link</a>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

You can't apply pesudo-classes (or anything else that appears in a selector) via the style attribute.

Answer (score 6):

The normal HTML way for inline styling is:

```
<a href="url" style="color:#cfe7fe";">Click me!</a>
```

But I am not sure how reliable that is in email templates.

You could always try: [(Although deprecated)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_fonts.asp)

```
<font color="blue"> <a href="url">Click me!</a> </font>
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit:** For inline hover try using:

```
onmouseover="this.style.color='blue';" 
onmouseout="this.style.color='black';"
```

But again I am not sure on email support for this.

Comment: I meant a color change when the mouse flies over the link.

Answer (score 4):

Some E-Mail clients support `style` tags, and thus the defining of pseudo-selectors. According to this list:

[Guide to CSS support in E-Mail clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

`:hover` is supported by a good number of clients.

You should be able to slip a `<style>` tag into the body if necessary. That's not valid, but rich E-Mails are such a minefield that that is going to hardly matter.

`:hover` is your only chance I think. It's not possible to define pseudo-selectors inline, and JavaScript is out because it's going to be blocked by most (or all?) clients.

Answer (score -1):

You can, however, you will not be able to change the color of the underline. You can wrap the the link text in a div and then wrap the div in a link, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><div style="margin: 0px;padding: 20px 50px;font-size: 50px; color: red;">GOOGLE</div></a>
```

The word "GOOGLE" will appear red, but with a blue underline. So that does not exactly solve your problem, I don't think.